# How to print to text usb printer in android

Tags: java, android

I am making a function to print using USB.
I've found a simple example and I'm trying to test it and transform it.
The print information was retrieved normally, and the permission was granted normally.

If you input text and click the print button, the thread starts, and it seems to go through an infinite loop. Which part is wrong??

***activity_main.xml***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/usbDevice"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:gravity="center" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/ed_txt"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:textSize="25dp"
        android:hint="Enter text to print" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/print"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:text="print" />
</LinearLayout>
```

***MainActivity.java***

```
package com.android.usb_printer;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.hardware.usb.UsbConstants;
import android.hardware.usb.UsbDevice;
import android.hardware.usb.UsbDeviceConnection;
import android.hardware.usb.UsbEndpoint;
import android.hardware.usb.UsbInterface;
import android.hardware.usb.UsbManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Iterator;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private UsbManager mUsbManager;
    private UsbDevice mDevice;
    private UsbDeviceConnection mConnection;
    private UsbInterface mInterface;
    private UsbEndpoint mEndPoint;
    private PendingIntent mPermissionIntent;
    EditText ed_txt;
    private static final String ACTION_USB_PERMISSION = "com.android.example.USB_PERMISSION";
    private static Boolean forceCLaim = true;

    HashMap<String, UsbDevice> mDeviceList;
    Iterator<UsbDevice> mDeviceIterator;
    byte[] testBytes;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        ed_txt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ed_txt);
        Button print = (Button) findViewById(R.id.print);

        mUsbManager = (UsbManager) getSystemService(Context.USB_SERVICE);
        mDeviceList = mUsbManager.getDeviceList();

        if (mDeviceList.size() > 0) {
            mDeviceIterator = mDeviceList.values().iterator();

            Toast.makeText(this, "Device List Size: " + String.valueOf(mDeviceList.size()), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.usbDevice);
            String usbDevice = "";
            while (mDeviceIterator.hasNext()) {
                UsbDevice usbDevice1 = mDeviceIterator.next();
                usbDevice += "\n" +
                        "DeviceID: " + usbDevice1.getDeviceId() + "\n" +
                        "DeviceName: " + usbDevice1.getDeviceName() + "\n" +
                        "Protocol: " + usbDevice1.getDeviceProtocol() + "\n" +
                        "Product Name: " + usbDevice1.getProductName() + "\n" +
                        "Manufacturer Name: " + usbDevice1.getManufacturerName() + "\n" +
                        "DeviceClass: " + usbDevice1.getDeviceClass() + " - " + translateDeviceClass(usbDevice1.getDeviceClass()) + "\n" +
                        "DeviceSubClass: " + usbDevice1.getDeviceSubclass() + "\n" +
                        "VendorID: " + usbDevice1.getVendorId() + "\n" +
                        "ProductID: " + usbDevice1.getProductId() + "\n";

                int interfaceCount = usbDevice1.getInterfaceCount();
                Toast.makeText(this, "INTERFACE COUNT: " + String.valueOf(interfaceCount), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                mDevice = usbDevice1;

                Toast.makeText(this, "Device is attached", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                textView.setText(usbDevice);
            }

            mPermissionIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, new Intent(ACTION_USB_PERMISSION), 0);
            IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(ACTION_USB_PERMISSION);
            registerReceiver(mUsbReceiver, filter);

            mUsbManager.requestPermission(mDevice, mPermissionIntent);
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Please attach printer via USB", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        print.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                print(mConnection, mInterface);
            }
        });
    }

    private void print(final UsbDeviceConnection connection, final UsbInterface usbInterface) {
        final String test = ed_txt.getText().toString() + "\n\n";
        testBytes = test.getBytes();

        if (usbInterface == null) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "INTERFACE IS NULL", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else if (connection == null) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "CONNECTION IS NULL", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else if (forceCLaim == null) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "FORCE CLAIM IS NULL", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {

            connection.claimInterface(usbInterface, forceCLaim);

            Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {

                    byte[] cut_paper = {0x1D, 0x56, 0x41, 0x10};
                    connection.bulkTransfer(mEndPoint, testBytes, testBytes.length, 0);
                    connection.bulkTransfer(mEndPoint, cut_paper, cut_paper.length, 0);
                }
            });
            thread.run();
        }
    }


    final BroadcastReceiver mUsbReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String action = intent.getAction();
            if (ACTION_USB_PERMISSION.equals(action)) {
                synchronized (this) {
                    UsbDevice device = (UsbDevice) intent.getParcelableExtra(UsbManager.EXTRA_DEVICE);

                    if (intent.getBooleanExtra(UsbManager.EXTRA_PERMISSION_GRANTED, false)) {
                        if (device != null) {
                            //call method to set up device communication
                            mInterface = device.getInterface(0);
                            mEndPoint = mInterface.getEndpoint(1);// 0 IN and  1 OUT to printer.
                            mConnection = mUsbManager.openDevice(device);

                        }
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(context, "PERMISSION DENIED FOR THIS DEVICE", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    };


    private String translateDeviceClass(int deviceClass) {

        switch (deviceClass) {

            case UsbConstants.USB_CLASS_APP_SPEC:
                return "Application specific USB class";

            case UsbConstants.USB_CLASS_AUDIO:
                return "USB class for audio devices";

            case UsbConstants.USB_CLASS_CDC_DATA:
                return "USB class for CDC devices (communications device class)";

            case UsbConstants.USB_CLASS_COMM:
                return "USB class for communication devices";

            case UsbConstants.USB_CLASS_CONTENT_SEC:
                return "USB class for content security devices";

            case UsbConstants.USB_CLASS_CSCID:
                return "USB class for content smart card devices";

            case UsbConstants.USB_CLASS_HID:
                return "USB class for human interface devices (for example, mice and keyboards)";

            case UsbConstants.USB_CLASS_HUB:
                return "USB class for USB hubs";

            case UsbConstants.USB_CLASS_MASS_STORAGE:
                return "USB class for mass storage devices";

            case UsbConstants.USB_CLASS_MISC:
                return "USB class for wireless miscellaneous devices";

            case UsbConstants.USB_CLASS_PER_INTERFACE:
                return "USB class indicating that the class is determined on a per-interface basis";

            case UsbConstants.USB_CLASS_PHYSICA:
                return "USB class for physical devices";

            case UsbConstants.USB_CLASS_PRINTER:
                return "USB class for printers";

            case UsbConstants.USB_CLASS_STILL_IMAGE:
                return "USB class for still image devices (digital cameras)";

            case UsbConstants.USB_CLASS_VENDOR_SPEC:
                return "Vendor specific USB class";

            case UsbConstants.USB_CLASS_VIDEO:
                return "USB class for video devices";

            case UsbConstants.USB_CLASS_WIRELESS_CONTROLLER:
                return "USB class for wireless controller devices";

            default:
                return "Unknown USB class!";
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved!!

Change to  `mEndPoint = mInterface.getEndpoint(0);`

```
  final BroadcastReceiver mUsbReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String action = intent.getAction();
            if (ACTION_USB_PERMISSION.equals(action)) {
                synchronized (this) {
                    UsbDevice device = (UsbDevice) intent.getParcelableExtra(UsbManager.EXTRA_DEVICE);

                    if (intent.getBooleanExtra(UsbManager.EXTRA_PERMISSION_GRANTED, false)) {
                        if (device != null) {
                            //call method to set up device communication
                            mInterface = device.getInterface(0);
                            mEndPoint = mInterface.getEndpoint(1);// 0 IN and  1 OUT to printer.
                            mConnection = mUsbManager.openDevice(device);

                        }
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(context, "PERMISSION DENIED FOR THIS DEVICE", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    };
```